# Submit an inherent from an extrinsic call?

Tags: inherent

I am looking to process deletions in batches yet avoid using `on_initialize()`.  Can I submit an inherent from the call to process next batch in a subsequent block?  If so, what would the code to create/submit the inherent look like?

```
    let LIMIT = 256;

    pub fn delete(origin: OriginFor<T>, id:u32) -> DispatchResult {
        let who = ensure_signed(origin)?;

        let items = getItemsFromStorage(id);
        let num_items = items.count();
        let num_deleted = remove_items_for(items, LIMIT);
        if (num_deleted < num_items) {
          // Create and submit inherent to delete/remove the remainder of the items
          //
          // Inherent: delete_remaining_items_for(id);
          // 
        }

        Ok(())
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `on_idle` if you want to avoid `on_initialize`.

Answer (score 0):

[Inherents](https://docs.substrate.io/fundamentals/transaction-types/#inherent-transactions)

> Typically, this type of transaction is not gossiped to other nodes or stored in the transaction queue. The data inserted using an inherent transaction is assumed to be valid without requiring specific validation.

Given that you probably want to gossip about this transaction so that it is verified among all collators. Perhaps, inherent is probably not the ideal solution for this.